# Matlab GUI: Resizing image(Loaded to push button) when the GUI window is resized

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have loaded an image into a Pushbutton and the property of GUI window resizable proportion. When ever the GUI window is resized the image does not fit the size of the push button.

I would like to have even the image resized like the push button.  What needs to be done for this. Sorry, I could not upload the image(website did not allowed me to do so)

Comment: Try adding links to the images in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [ResizeFcn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html#zmw57dd0e162669) property of the figure window, and put code to resize the image to fit the new button dimensions into the callback function.

Comment: I did not understand what you said. Would please help me on this. Here is my GUI(GUIDE) code. This code I have included in the OpeningFcn of my Main function.                                baseFileName = 'Close.png'; i=imread(baseFileName); set(handles.pushbutton1,'CData',i); and What do I need to do now? PLease help me on this.

Comment: If you post a short but complete example: including generating the pushbutton, also a link to the image file, how you set the OpenFcn, as a short piece of code that I can take and execute on my computer – then I'll try to make it work. Please include that code in your question by editing, and be sure to explain what needs to be explained.